# Is there a type theory in which the equivalence of identically shaped inductive datatypes is representable?

Tags: types, coq, idris, dependent-type, type-theory

Say I have two inductively defined datatypes:

```
Inductive list1 (A : Type) : Type :=
 | nil1 : list1 A
 | cons1 : A -> list1 A -> list1 A.
```

and

```
Inductive list2 (A : Type) : Type :=
 | nil2 : list2 A
 | cons2 : A -> list2 A -> list2 A.
```

For any `P (list1 a)` I should be able to construct a `P (list2 a)`, by applying the exact same method I used to construct `P (list1 a)` except replacing `nil1` with `nil2`, `list1` with `list2` and `cons1` with `cons2`. Similarly, any function that takes `list1 a` as a parameter could be extended to take a `list2 a`.

Is there a type system that allows me to speak of two datatypes having the same shape in this manner (having identically shaped constructors), and prove `P (list1 a) -> P (list2 a)`? For instance, is this something that univalence, HOTT, or a cubical/observational type system allows? It might also allow defining functions like `reverse: list_like a -> list_like a` that accept both `list1`s and `list2`s as parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HoTT with univalence, it is indeed provable that `list1 A` is equal to `list2 A` for all `A`. Given a proof `p : list1 A = list2 A`, transport (or `subst`) gives you `P (list1 A) -> P (list2 A)` for any `P`. In cubical type theories, such transporting may also compute as expected. To my knowledge, cubical type theory ([CCHM](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01378906/document) or [cartesian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01800.pdf)) is the only setting where this currently works. [`cubicaltt`](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt) is the most usable (but still not really practical) implementation.

Comment: What would `p : list1 A = list2 A` look like, just `exists f: list1 A -> list2 A, g: list2 A -> list1 A, forall x: list1 A, y: list2 A, g (f x) = x /\ f (g y) = y`?

Comment: @LogicChains There's some `isoToEq` term which turns such a `(f, g, p)` triple into an equality. The equality proof might have more complicated internal data though.